# Rationale behind elseif or elif statements in some languages

Tags: php, c++, if-statement, syntax

I'm not sure whether this is a good question, but this was just bothering me from a theoretical perspective. Can anyone explain why some languages like php have an explicit elseif/elif while others like c++ or java make do with just if and else. It would seem that less keywords to remember is preferable to more keywords. Is there any benefit to having an elseif statement available ?

P.S. I am writing a book on programming languages and I am collecting opinions on language design theory

EDIT: Thank you for pointing this out. I realize now that in Python specifically it is important due to the whitespace / indentation rule. I have changed my example from Python to PHP.

Comment: Just a guess, but if you have a series of elif statements the conditions are only evaluated until one is true and then the rest are ignored. With only if, every condition would have to be evaluated. i.e. it is less work to have a series of elifs.

Comment: In python specifically, nesting if/else would lead to way too many indentations since white-space is meaningful.

Comment: Instead of asking, IMHO you should research it yourself first. It'd be nice, isn't it? There's a lot of articles about why Python uses `elif`, for example.

Comment: @kalhartt Thank you that is actually important for python. I did not think of that. However for other languages - the question remains.

Comment: The entire philosophy of C when it was designed was to keep the language as small as possible, simply covering the very basics of control and flow. The idea was that everything else would be done by libraries. So it would have gone totally against the design criteria to add a redundant keyword like elif.

Comment: Another thought, promoting elif keyword usage might help avoid the infamous 'dangling else' ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, `elseif` avoids excessive indentations as @kalhartt commented, for python (mandatory) and for other languages like c++ (optional but customary).

But more importantly, I think `elseif` is a helpful feature that hints about the workflow in the sense that,

1) there is nothing else in the `else` branch, i.e. we don't have complicated structures like

```
if (A) {
}
else {
  if (B) {...} else { ... }
  i++;...
}
```

2) it helps to create a **linear** structure similar to the `switch` statement, where

```
   switch (a) {
      case 1:
        ...
      case 2:
        ...
      case 3
        ...
      default:
   }
```

maps to:

```
   if (a == 1) {
   }
   elseif (a == 2) {
   }
   elseif (a == 3) {
   }
   else{
   }
```

The `if ... elseif ...` form is a bit more verbose, but more powerful, i.e. with less stringent requirement on the conditional for each "case". For example, you can use

```
elseif (a > 3 && a < 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the benefit is to simplify code. Say there are a list of choices and you are using if statements to do an action per each different choice. It is easier to use elseif statements to narrow down the choices. Also, it has greater readability.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But does "elseif" really have better readability than "else if". The question is - is it really worth it to have a separate keyword in the language. (With the exception of python)